# Making protocol conformance for Firebase integration in Swift project

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building an application for iOS devices and I'm trying to use Protocol conformances to make the code more flexible.

In particular, I created a `DatabaseService` protocol that provides the methods to query a generic database.

Having used Firebase Firestore before, I knew that some methods return a `ListenerRegistration` element that can be `remove()`'d.

In my attempt to make this behavior generic, I created a `Disposable` protocol and set it as the return type of some `DatabaseService` methods.

While creating the `FirestoreDatabaseService` implementation that conforms to `DatabaseService`, however, I noticed that `ListenerRegistration` is a protocol and not a class.

So I decided to try to conform `ListenerRegistration` to `Disposable` with this extension:

```
extension Disposable where Self: ListenerRegistration {
  // The Disposable protocol has only this function, 
  // that disposes the listener on deinit.
  func dispose() {
    // This makes the Disposable dispose on the Registration's remove()
    self.remove()
  }
}
```

So my `FirestoreDatabaseService` methods return `ListenerRegistration`s that I assumed would be compatible with `Disposable`.
The compiler, however, suggests me to force cast the result `as! Disposable` which does not seem right.

What am I missing? I'm sure there must be a better way.

Thank you very much.

---

EDIT: To clarify my actual need:

I want to have a generic `DatabaseService` protocol that can be used as a blueprint for any actual database-related service that I might add. (Firebase, AWS, Azure etc.)

For example, the function `fetchDeck(id: String, completion: @escaping (Deck) -> Void) -> Disposable` might be implemented in `FirestoreDatabaseService` as

```
fetchDeck(id: String, completion: @escaping (Deck) -> Void) -> Disposable {
    return Firestore.firestore().document("decks/\(id)").addSnapshotListener { snapshot, error in
        // Here goes the actual code
    }
}
```

The problem is that this function would return a `ListenerRegistration` while my protocol conformance requires a `Disposable`.

How can I bridge the `ListenerRegistration` to a `Disposable`, with both of them being protocols? I don't want to use `ListenerRegistration` as return type, because that would not be backend-independent.

To be more specific, my `Disposable` protocol requires a `dispose()` function to be implemented, that is the behavior expressed by `ListenerRegistration`'s [`remove()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Protocols/ListenerRegistration)

---

EDIT: Solution to this particular problem

I have found a solution that might help anyone in the same situation. This might not apply to you if you need a different type of conformance.

Instead of trying to return the `ListenerRegistration` itself, I created an `AnonymousDisposable` following RxSwift's blueprint.

The `AnonymousDisposable` conforms to `Disposable` and takes a closure as a parameter which is the code to call on `dispose()`. Now I can return the instance of `AnonymousDisposable` and call its `dispose()` when necessary.

You can read more [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxSwift/Disposables/AnonymousDisposable.swift).

Comment: Can you clarify the actual question *I'm sure there must be a better way* a better way to do what? It's difficult to develop an answer as we don't know the purpose. Removing an existing listener is one line of code *some_listener.remove()* why do you need additional code to replace the one  line approach? Also, it's hard to make Firestore a 'generic database' as every path to every piece of data is unique, so the results of every observe or query would be specific to that function. Maybe a bit more info and/or code would clarify the question

Comment: Hi, I updated the original post, this might make things a bit clearer.